# push_back for vector not adding all the elements from for loop after boolean expression using lambda function - c++

Tags: c++

I have to insert a number into a vector after a certain Boolean condition has been met. My code is only adding the first expression but not the others:

```
vector<int> f(int n){

    vector<int> p;

    for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i){
    
        if(all_of(p.begin(), p.end(), [&](int pn){ return pn % i == 0; }))
            p.push_back(i);
    }
    return p;
}

int main(){
    auto v = f(30)
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

I only get the first number added to the vector but not the rest. Any idea where the code has gone wrong ?

Comment: Stepping through your code with a debugger should highlight the problem. Your code does the opposite of what you want. It will iterate over the values of `i` and only insert values *as long as* the condition is `true`. Once you add a value that doesn't fit the predicate `all_of` will never return `true` again, because an element in the collection doesn't match the predicate anymore. You can try using the inverse predicate with `std::none_of`.

Answer (score 1):

You add the single 2 in the first loop iteration, then `i > 2` and the predicate `2 % i == 0` is `2 == 0`, is always false. Therefore the resulting vector `p` gets the single element `{ 2 }`.